# Customize Android development environment resolution (Android x86 and eclipse combination)

Tags: android, linux, x86, screen, development-environment

I a few days i will get a new Samsumg Galaxy SII and now i want to try developing apps for Android, so i installed eclipse and the ADT however the emulator seems to be painfully slow so i found a workaround: installing the generic x86 version in Oracle VirtualBox and connect it via `adb connect <ip>` to eclipse and it works extremely well.

However i am running in a "high res" version or something like that and i would like to scale it down to some more common resolution to imitate the resolution of smartphones like my Galaxy. Is anyone familiar with this customization?

Comment: android x86, is not a "generic" version of android. In fact, it is not official affiliated with google at all. Rather, it is an independent project.

Comment: @Ian: You're absolutely right. With generic i wanted to highlight, that my version is no Eee-PC version or something like that. It's just generic-x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how one can control the resolution at install. However, you if you run it live from the disk, you can highlight VESA mode. Then,

> If you want to use higher resolution, you can edit the boot option by
>   pressing TAB, change vga=788 (800x600) to vga=791 (1024x768) or
>   vga=794 (1280x1024), and press Enter. **You can also use vga=ask to see
>   all available modes**. But please note Android will only work under
>   16-bit mode.

http://www.android-x86.org/documents/virtualboxhowto

For 800x480, you'll want video mode 375.

I've tested on 2.2 and 2.3: "android-x86-2.3-RC1-asus_laptop.iso" and http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/detail?name=android-x86-2.2-generic.iso&can=2&q= and i can get that video mode to work fine. After entering vga=ask, hit enter to see all the modes, then enter 375.

Comment: Suppose I want to have a resolution of 480x800. It is no common resolution... how to boot in this mode?

Comment: there are dozens of available resolutions. 375 is 480x800

Comment: I tried vga=ask however it doesn't provide the 375 resolution for example!

Comment: did you build the iso yourself?
You don't necessarily need to go into the ask menu in order to boot 375. What does it do when you enter that number?

Comment: Downloaded as a daily build and made by myself. "Undefined video mode number: 375" appears as the error message.

Comment: hm. there may something special i did during the build. I am running 2.2.

Comment: i can get it fine with the iso from the site. Check me update.

Comment: 1. Your update is wrong as your link points to another image and the screen resolution you mentioned is the other way round (i want 480x800) ;-) 2. It still does not work, have a look: http://imgur.com/QH3z6

Comment: hm. I am using VMware. Perhaps that is the difference. As far as getting the inverted resolution, idk if we can get androidx86 in portrait mode.The only way is to specify a custom resolution through the VM, i believe.